# The use of the verb "fly" in context

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use the verb *fly* on its own meaning traveling by plane as a passenger. For example:

> When did you last **fly**?

Comment: I guess, yes, I've heard people say "When did you last fly to (somewhere)?" or "Did you fly to (somewhere)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct to use the verb *fly* on its own meaning traveling by plane as a passenger?

One hundred percent yes!

> To "fly" is *"to travel by aircraft, or to go somewhere or cross something in an aircraft"* (Cambridge).

You can see that the "plane" aspect is built into the definition. See the examples from Cambridge and Collins:

> - We flew to Paris.
> - We are flying at a height of 36,000 feet.
> - She has to fly thousands of miles every year for her job.
> - Who was the first person to fly (across) the Atlantic?
> - He flew to Los Angeles.
> - He flew back to London.
> - Mr Baker flew in from Moscow.

Comment: What about using it without specifying where someone flew? For example:" When did you last fly" meaning when was the last time you used a plane?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope That is fine as well. See the third example. Also, we often say things like *"I will be flying tomorrow night"* without mentioning the destination (particularly when it isn't important or when the listener knows it). Here is another example: *"I get sick when I fly!"* or *"I hate flying, it makes me sick."*

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.  The person might not have flown by themselves, but they still were flying via an airplane.  They were flying inside the plane.

Comment: I flew to Barcelona last week; I didn't have to flap my arms a lot; I just had to pay some money to easyJet.